# Data connection to Internet

Tags: android

My app is making a connection, using the DefaultHttpClient and HttpPost, to the internet. I configured it to have Internet permission (manifest) and all is working well when my device is connected via WIFI. Switching off the WIFI and trying to use a data connection via the phone network seems to fail (there is not really a connection error, but it seems the data (from the server) is never arriving.

Any suggestions to what causes this behaviour are welcome. Do I need to add more permissions ?

Thanks,

Vincent

Comment: your question is not complete. do you have any data connection enabled on you device?

Comment: no need to restart phone. its worked if you are use perfect code. please post your code here.

Answer (score 0):

check this link. http://talk.maemo.org/archive/index.php/t-36774.html

Edge operates over the same frequencies as GSM voice so you can't do both at once.
A wifi or 3g connection will persist though

Comment: That is very much a possibility. It would be helpful to know the type of network the device is connecting to (or the type of device & carrier since we could figure out from there). If the device is not running on EDGE or CDMA (Verizon 3G) there might be a problem with the app. Otherwise it's a non-issue as you've mentioned.